# JQuery Validation: How to add custom rule to two input fields but with different name value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use JQuery Validation(https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validation my form. I write custom rule and use the rule to validation the input field.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("onlyoneuser", function (value, element) {
        var username = /^[^,，\s]*$/;
        return this.optional(element) || username.test(value);
    }, "只允许填写一位指派者");

    form.validate({
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        },

        rules: {
            "aonep-roject": {
                projectcheck: true,
            },
            "onlyoneuser": {
                onlyoneuser: true,
            }
        },

    });
```

I would like to use the same rule to validate two input fields. But the two fields have different name values, like   . How to apply the sample to these two fields ?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`onlyoneuser: true` The true is param give onlyoneuser method.

```
 function (value, element,param) 
{
    //param == true
    //value is filed value
    //element is input
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? I do not quite understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3872057 
"onlyoneuser": 
{
         onlyoneuser: true,//call the  onlyoneuser method
}